# decorate lxml.etree._Element methods

Tags: python, methods, decorator, lxml, patch

I tried to decorate/override/patch the *'get'*, *'text'*, and *'findtext'* methods of **lxml.etree._Element**,
but it seems like it's impossible to achieve, as all the attributes are read-only, probably because it's not written in python. Is there a way to decorate those methods?
Thanks for any suggestions..

Comment: What exactly is your goal? Why do you want to decorate those methods?

Comment: lxml is returning unicode strings everywhere, and I want to wrap these methods with my to_str function, so I will get back normal strings. I call them many times in the code, so I don't want to wrap it everywhere manually, but rather decorate it the source method.

Comment: I would suggest using unicode strings everywhere, and encoding to a specific character set only when outputting them. Keeping the internals of your program in Unicode can prevent a lot of headaches (with a non-ASCII character in my last name I'm often reminded of issues with character sets).

Comment: Actually lxml returns 'smart strings' which is a unicode subclass that seems to trip up sqlalchemy's encoding attempts in my code, so I can understand the OP's need very well. I don't have a decent solution, though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the comments, I listened to the suggestion to use unicode everywhere, and encode to string just when outputting the data. Thanks for that, however I was curious after all to accomplish the task I wanted anyway, so here's what I've came up with, an lxml._Element class wrapper:

https://github.com/integricho/lxmlproxy

Maybe someone else will find it useful for something after all, as I did not find other orthodox solutions.